# Update the mysql database using Asp.Net

Tags: c#, jquery, mysql, asp.net, ajax

Here I got a web form I used select Query and displayed it a form and i need it to update using Query I tried lost of method. I couldn't update,it just updating but passing the old value instead of new changed value.

```
Here is the form 



<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Editcar.aspx.cs" MasterPageFile="MasterPage2.master" Inherits ="Editcar" %>
<asp:Content ID="formContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">


 <form id="form1" runat="server" class="col-md-10" methode="post" >


    <asp:Table ID="GridView1" class="nav-justified" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Height="628px" Width="763px">
        <asp:TableRow>
           <asp:TableCell>
                <h4> Car name:</h4>

           </asp:TableCell>
           <asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TextBox ID="id" runat="server" name="id" Width="301px" Text='<%# Eval("id") %>' Visible="False" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:TextBox ID="carmake" runat="server" Font-Names="carmake" Width="301px" Text='<%#  Eval("car_make") %>' CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>

           </asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableRow>
           <asp:TableCell>
                <h4> Car model:</h4>
           </asp:TableCell>
           <asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TextBox ID="carmodel" runat="server" name="carmodel" Text='<%#  Eval("car_model") %>' Width="301px" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
           </asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableRow>
           <asp:TableCell>
                <h4> Price: </h4>
           </asp:TableCell>
           <asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TextBox ID="price"  name="price" runat="server" Width="301px"  CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
           </asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableRow>
           <asp:TableCell>
                <h4> Discounted Price If: </h4>
           </asp:TableCell>
           <asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TextBox ID="d_price" name="d_price" runat="server" Width="301px"  CssClass="form-control"/>
           </asp:TableCell></asp:TableRow><asp:TableRow>
           <asp:TableCell> <h4>Car image (Type url)</h4></asp:TableCell><asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" ID="image"  name="image" runat="server" />Just Location
            </asp:TableCell></asp:TableRow><asp:TableRow>
           <asp:TableCell><h4>Avilability</h4></asp:TableCell><asp:TableCell>
                 <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" ID="avail"  name="avail" runat="server" />Just Location
           </asp:TableCell></asp:TableRow><asp:TableRow>
           <asp:TableCell><h4>Quantity</h4></asp:TableCell><asp:TableCell>
                 <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" ID="quantity"   name="quantity" runat="server" />Just Location
           </asp:TableCell></asp:TableRow><asp:TableRow>
           <asp:TableCell>
                <h4>Long description </h4>
           </asp:TableCell><asp:TableCell>

                <asp:TextBox ID="details" name="details" runat="server" Width="295px"  CssClass="form-control" Height="81px" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
           </asp:TableCell></asp:TableRow><asp:TableRow>
           <asp:TableCell>
                <h4>Year </h4>
           </asp:TableCell><asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TextBox ID="year" name="year" runat="server" Width="295px"  CssClass="form-control" ></asp:TextBox>
           </asp:TableCell></asp:TableRow><asp:TableRow>
           <asp:TableCell>
                <h4>Special Discounted(0 0r 1) </h4>
           </asp:TableCell><asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TextBox ID="special" name="special"  runat="server" Width="295px"  CssClass="form-control"  ></asp:TextBox>
           </asp:TableCell></asp:TableRow></asp:Table><asp:Button ID="button" OnClick="button_click" runat="server"  Cssclass="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" Text="Update the car" />

   </form>
```

HERE is the code fore cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

public partial class Editcar : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;

    using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constr))
    {
        var id = Request.QueryString["id"];
        string selectquery = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE id=" + @id;
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(selectquery);
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)

        {
            newid.Text = dr["id"].ToString();
            carmake.Text = dr["car_make"].ToString();
            carmodel.Text = dr["car_model"].ToString();
            price.Text = dr["unitprice"].ToString();
            d_price.Text = dr["discountprice"].ToString();
            image.Text = dr["image"].ToString();
            quantity.Text = dr["quantity"].ToString();
            avail.Text = dr["availability"].ToString();
            details.Text = dr["details"].ToString();
            year.Text = dr["year"].ToString();
            special.Text = dr["special"].ToString();
        }
    }
}

public void button_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string constor = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(constor);

    string sql = "Update product SET car_make=@carmake, car_model=@carmodel, UnitPrice=@price, Discountprice=@d_price, image=@image, Quantity=@quantity, availability=@avail, details=@details, year=@year, special=@special  WHERE id= @id";
    var cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);

    conn.Open();
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", newid.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@carmake", carmake.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@carmodel", carmodel.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", price.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d_price", d_price.Text); // put zero if no discount
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image", image.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantity", quantity.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@avail", avail.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@details", details.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@year", year.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@special", special.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", newid.Text);

    var ex = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    if (ex == 1)
    {
        Response.Redirect("AdminList.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("Error");
    }
    conn.Close();
}
}
```

It's Just updating but not getting the table value

I used ajax too it didn't work

Comment: you don't appear to be associating the parameters with the MySQL command object. You declare the parameters and populate them, but they are not associated with the command, so they are not passed to the DB. Try using `cmd.Parameters.Add(param[0]);` for instance, and repeat for each parameter (or directly declare the new parameter object inside the Add brackets, for brevity). Repeat for all your required parameters. Or even `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue()` could save you even more code, then you just specify the name and value and let .NET infer the data type.

Comment: Those code worked for INSERT, Thank you for your time, Let me try with

Comment: it should work identically for any statement, select, update, delete, insert - it shouldn't matter. The point is to associate the parameters with the command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not associating the parameters with the MySQL command object. You declare the parameters and populate them, but they are not associated with the command, so they are not passed to the DB.

You can use either:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(param[0]);
```

for instance, and repeat for each parameter.

Or use the `AddWithValue` method for greater brevity:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@carmake", carmake);
```

This just specifies the name and the value, and lets .NET infer the data type. Again, repeat for each parameter. Then you can get rid of the array and all the declarations of `new MySqlParameter`.

Lastly your SQL string should be like this:

```
"Update product SET car_make = @carmake, car_model= @carmodel, " //...etc
```

i.e. not `" + @carmake + ",` - that's just concatenating the values of your form fields, which happen to have exactly the same names as your SQL parameters.

Comment: That i used but it taking not value instead like  '.WebControls.TextBox,' updating to database

Comment: "that I tried". Which of the two suggestions did you try? If it's putting "'.WebControls.TextBox" into the database, then there's a good chance that's because the value of the "carkmake" string is "'.WebControls.TextBox". That is not the fault of the SQL parameter. Above in the comments you said my suggestion worked, so I posted it as the answer for future readers. Now you say it doesn't work??

Comment: this is the error `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '.WebControls.TextBox, car_model=System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox, UnitPrice=Sys' at line 1` instead it like that

Comment: Is "button_click" your button event? If so, you can't put all the string values as input parameters to it. The only parameters you can use are "object sender, EventArgs e". Your commented-out version of button_click is more correct in this respect. So then you need to add `carmake.Text` as the parameter value. And your comment, while helpful, didn't answer either of the questions I asked in my previous comment. Answers to those would still be useful.

Comment: for button event i used `protected void button_click(object sender, EventArgs e)` i'll update the coding above

Comment: `string sql = "Update product SET car_make=" + @carmake + ", car_model=" + @carmodel + ", UnitPrice=" + @price + ", Discountprice=" + @d_price + ", image=" + @image + ", Quantity=" + @quantity + ", availability=" + @avail + ", details=" + @details + ", year=" + @year + ", special=" + @special + "  WHERE id=" + @id;` i changed it like this `string sql = "Update product SET car_make=@carmake, car_model=@carmodel, UnitPrice=@price, Discountprice=@d_price, image=@image, Quantity=@quantity, availability=@avail, details=@details, year=@year, special=@special  WHERE id="+@id;` now it no error message

Comment: but not updating the database

Comment: Ok I just spotted another problem - your SQL string. See the edit to the answer.

Comment: While it passing to the `if(ex == 1)` the condition failed it throwing a error

Comment: While it passing to the `if(ex == 1)` the condition failed it throwing a error above `car_make=@carmake` only i tried in Where it shown error so i let `WHERE id="+@id` coz id is got through `var id = Request.QueryString["id"];` and tried assigning to parameter like  this too `cmd.AddWithValue("@newid", id);` then `Where id=@newid` no result

Comment: What error? Just saying "there's an error" is no use if you don't say what the error message is. If you mean this `Response.Write("Error");` that's not a real error, that's just you trying to redirect to a page that probably doesn't exist - maybe it should be Error.aspx?

Comment: SQL fatal error am talked about, i just changed the coding it just redirecting to my page but not updating any data. Mean it not taking any value from the TexBox just running with any change in database.

Comment: Ok so, again: **What's the error?** "fatal error" is generic, could be anything. I am happy to help you, but you need to provide clear and proper information. Also if you have changed your code further in any way, I need to know what you've changed, and why. I cannot read your mind or see your screen. From your earlier code posting, `WHERE id="+@id` needs to be `WHERE id=@id"`, just like all the other parameters.

Comment: So, that's a description of what you _want to do_. **What is happening now?** It's perfectly possible to do an UPDATE this way, but clearly there's some issue with the code. Edit the question with the code **as it is now**, and a clear description of any errors or problems you're having. At the moment it seems like you keep changing it, and you're not giving me a clear description of the issues, so I can only guess.

Comment: there is no error but, issue is it not updating my database. `if(ex == 1)` his satisfy but it not updating my database it still Same old data. i updated the code

Comment: Why are you doing `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", newid.Text);` twice? If `ex` really does equal 1, then that means 1 row was affected - presumably something is getting updated in there?

Comment: Thank you for the time, I just figure it when is post data from form it one again  loading the `Page_load`. the right method to use in my answer 3. Once again thank you!

Comment: ah yes that would do it. A long time since I used ASP.NET WebForms, I forgot how stupid the Page_Load thing is. Happy to help. If my answer has helped you in any way, please consider upvoting and/or marking as accepted answer - thanks :-)

Comment: Sorry! i need nearly 10 reputation for Vote your answer! Once Again thank you! You can Accept my answer no 3.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Right method For CS file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

public partial class Editcar : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.IsPostBack)
        {
            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;

            using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constr))
            {
                var id = Request.QueryString["id"];

                string selectquery = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE id=" + @id;

                MySqlCommand cmmd = new MySqlCommand(selectquery);
                cmmd.Connection = con;
                cmmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                con.Open();
                cmmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmmd);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);

                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    newid.Text = dr["id"].ToString();
                    carmake.Text = dr["car_make"].ToString();
                    carmodel.Text = dr["car_model"].ToString();
                    price.Text = dr["unitprice"].ToString();
                    d_price.Text = dr["discountprice"].ToString();
                    image.Text = dr["image"].ToString();
                    qnty.Text = dr["quantity"].ToString();
                    avbl.Text = dr["availability"].ToString();
                    details.Text = dr["details"].ToString();
                    year.Text = dr["year"].ToString();
                    special.Text = dr["special"].ToString();
               }
         }
    }
}

public void button_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string constor = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(constor);

    string sql = "Update product SET car_make=@carmake, car_model=@carmodel, UnitPrice=@price, Discountprice=@d_price, image=@image, Quantity=@quantity, availability=@avail, details=@details, year=@year, special=@special  WHERE id= @id";

    var cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
    conn.Open();
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@carmake", carmake.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@carmodel", carmodel.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", price.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d_price", d_price.Text); // put zero if no discount
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image", image.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantity", qnty.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@avail", avbl.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@details", details.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@year", year.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@special", special.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", newid.Text);

    var ex = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    if (ex == 1)
    {
        Response.Redirect("AdminList.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("Error");
    }
    conn.Close();
    }
  }
```

Here i used 
    `if (!this.IsPostBack)` so that the conduction prevented `Page_load` code  affect the Button_Click data.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the same method i used for adding(INSERT) from the form

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

public partial class Admingroup_Addcar : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void ExecuteInsert(string id, string carmake, string carmodel, string price, string d_price, string image,
        string quantity, string details, string year, string special)
    {
        var constr = "SERVER=localhost;" +
                     "DATABASE=carsstore;" +
                     "UID=root;" +
                     "PASSWORD=;";

        var conn = new MySqlConnection(constr);

        var avail = 1;

        var sql =
            "INSERT INTO product (id, car_make, car_model, UnitPrice, Discountprice, image, Quantity, availability, details, year, special) VALUES ('" +
            @id + "','" + @carmake + "','" + @carmodel + "','" + @price + "','" + @d_price + "','" + @image + "','" +
            @quantity + "','" + @avail + "','" + @details + "','" + @year + "','" + @special + "');";

        try
        {
            conn.Open();

            var cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
            var param = new MySqlParameter[11];

            param[0] = new MySqlParameter("@id", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 4);
            param[1] = new MySqlParameter("@carmake", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
            param[2] = new MySqlParameter("@carmodel", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
            param[3] = new MySqlParameter("@price", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
            param[4] = new MySqlParameter("@d_price", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 100); // put zero if no discount
            param[5] = new MySqlParameter("@image", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 300);
            param[6] = new MySqlParameter("@quantity", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 300);
            param[7] = new MySqlParameter("@avail", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 2);
            param[8] = new MySqlParameter("@details", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 2000);
            param[9] = new MySqlParameter("@year", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 4);
            param[10] = new MySqlParameter("@special", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 2);

            param[0].Value = id;
            param[1].Value = carmake;
            param[2].Value = carmodel;
            param[3].Value = price;
            param[4].Value = d_price;
            param[5].Value = image;
            param[6].Value = quantity;
            param[7].Value = avail;
            param[8].Value = details;
            param[9].Value = year;
            param[10].Value = special;

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            var msg = "Insert Error:";
            msg += ex.Message;
            throw new Exception(msg);
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }

    protected void button_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (price.Text != d_price.Text)
        {
            //call the method to execute insert to the database
            ExecuteInsert(id.Text, carmake.Text,
                carmodel.Text,
                price.Text,
                d_price.Text,
                image.Text,
                quantity.SelectedItem.Text,
                details.Text,
                year.Text,
                special.Text
                );
            Response.Write("Record was successfully added!");
            ClearControls(Page);
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("Record Error");
            d_price.Focus();
        }
    }

    public static void ClearControls(Control Parent)
    {
        if (Parent is TextBox)
        {
            (Parent as TextBox).Text = string.Empty;
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (Control c in Parent.Controls)
                ClearControls(c);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked we can use the same method but some change in sql Query like `var sql ="Update Product SET car_make ='" +@carmake +"` like this. But update is throwing error or it not updating